# Docker: How to display a page in IE from Virtual Machine created in Hyper-V Manager

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-swarm

I have created a docker swarm in three of the VM created with Hyper-V Manager. I installed the tutum/hello-world images and running on two of the worker node.

How do I use the local machine to show the hello world page on IE?

I can ping the master node of the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the docker swarm mode create the service with the below command.

```
docker service create -p 8080:80 --name helloworld tutum/hello-world
```

Try accessing with the below URL.

```
<IP Address of any node in swarm>:8080
```